# Seaborn clustermap and multiple color labeling of columns

Tags: seaborn

Per [seaborn.clustermap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), **col_colors** segment, you can pass a `pandas.DataFrame` object as a `col_colors` attribute to get mapping. However, when I pass a DataFrame, I get correct labels, but no colors. Example code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data=sns.load_dataset("iris")
data.pop("species")

color_pal = ["r","r","b","b"]
color_th = ["y","g","y","g"]
color_df = pd.DataFrame([color_pal,color_th],index=["type","size"]).T

sns.clustermap(data=data,col_colors=color_df)
```

The `iris` dataset consists of four columns :

```
sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width
```

The "idea" behind the test code above is to color all `sepal` as red, all `petal` as blue, all `length` as yellow, all `width` as green. So `sepal_length` would have one level red, and other level yellow. When I pass the above code to clustermap, I get the following plot:
[image]

Correct labels, but no color whatsoever.

But when I pass the following code:

```
sns.clustermap(data=data,col_colors=color_df["type"].values)
```

I get the next picture:

[image]

I get correct colors, but I don't have any label and I get only one label. I've found [this](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1395) issue where it reiterates that colors are also matched to the data by their index - I presume that's why I don't get correct coloring.

What I want is to get multiple levels of labeling with correct labels and correct colors.

I can understand how indices are matched for row colors - but I can't really understand how it uses indices for matching column colors. How can I make this code work.

Comment: @JohanC Yes, thank you, that works perfectly. So indices of data for row color, and columns of data as column colors. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the index of `color_df` is mapped to the columns of `data`. So, `color_df = pd.DataFrame([color_pal,color_th],index=["type","size"], columns=data.columns).T` or, without the transpose: `color_df = pd.DataFrame({"type": color_pal, "size": color_th}, index=data.columns)` would set a color row for `type` and another for `size`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = sns.load_dataset("iris")
data.pop("species")

color_pal = ["r", "r", "b", "b"]
color_th = ["y", "g", "y", "g"]
color_df = pd.DataFrame({"type": color_pal, "size": color_th}, index=data.columns)

sns.clustermap(data=data, col_colors=color_df)
```

[image: sns.clustermap with two rows of col_colors]